# Compute $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{n \sin(\frac{x}{n})}{x(1+x^2)}dx$ using Dominated Convergence Theorem (just require checking)

Tags: measure-theory

The question ask me to compute $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{n \sin(\frac{x}{n})}{x(1+x^2)}dx$$ by using Dominated Convergence Theorem.

---

Here is what I did.

I know as $n \to \infty$, $\frac{n \sin(\frac{x}{n})}{x(1+x^2)} \to \frac{1}{1+x^2}$

And $$\mid \frac{n \sin(\frac{x}{n})}{x(1+x^2)} \mid \leq\frac{n}{x(1+x^2)}\leq \frac{n}{1+x^2}=g(x)$$

$g(x)$ is integrable on $[0,\infty]$ since $\int_0^\infty \mid g(x)\mid dx \lt \infty$.

Hence,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{n \sin(\frac{x}{n})}{x(1+x^2)}dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx =\pi/2$$

Am I right? did I miss anything or something that is unclear?

Comment: The dominating function $g(x)$ should not depend on $n$.

Comment: Isn't the inequality $\dfrac{n}{x(1 + x^{2})} \leq \dfrac{n}{1 + x^{2}}$ only true if $x \geq 1$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Since $n \gg 0$ I can't say $\frac{n}{1+x^2}\leq \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ right?

Comment: @user46944 You are right ...

Comment: @SamC So if your $g(x)$ were OK, you could only do this argument if integrating over $[1, \infty)$.  But you're integrating over $[0, \infty)$, so your $g(x)$ would need to dominate $|f_{n}(x)|$ over all of $[0, \infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $|\sin x| \le |x|$ for all $x$, you can take $g(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x^2}$ as your dominating function.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem. I just remember $\sin \leq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$ we have:
$$ \frac{n}{x}\cdot\sin\frac{x}{n}\leq 1 \tag{1}$$
hence it follows that:
$$ I_n=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{n\,\sin\frac{x}{n}}{x(1+x^2)}\,dx \leq \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}.\tag{2} $$
We may also notice, by considering Laplace or Fourier transforms, that:
$$ I_n = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot\frac{n}{1+n^2 x^2}\,dx = \frac{\pi n}{2}\left(1-e^{-\frac{1}{n}}\right)\xrightarrow[\small n\to +\infty]{}\frac{\pi}{2}.\tag{3}$$